# making it so "email addresses" aren't turned into hyperlinks

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

Some algorithms in SSH are denoted like `aes128-gcm@openssh.com`. The problem with this is that if you mention this in a Markdown file, Docusaurus 1 will convert it to a mailto: hyperlink. I don't mind it being done for legit emails but that's not a legit email. I mean, I suppose it could be, but in this context, it's not supposed to be an email address.

I could do what I did here and turn it into a code block but I don't want to turn every algorithm name into a code block. eg. `aes128-ctr` doesn't need to be a code block to prevent it from being a hyperlink. And sure, in *this* context, making it a code block makes sense, but imho it doesn't make sense in my context (using them in a table, listing the supported algorithms for various different SSH clients).

Thanks!

Comment: Does adding an empty link before the `@` work, e.g. `aes128-gcm[]()@openssh.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `linkify` (a Remarkable plugin) is [turned on by default](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/master/packages/docusaurus-1.x/lib/core/renderMarkdown.js#L108) in the core and there's no way to turn it off at the moment unless more configs are added to `siteConfig.js`, which we are hesitant to add at this point in time since we're focusing on [Docusaurus 2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/). Docusaurus 2 doesn't have linkifying behavior by default, so you could consider using that instead.

Pull requests are welcome though, or the `aes128-gcm[]()@openssh.com` hack which @chris mentioned in a comment above.